# Altering column data SQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a set of car data, one of the columns represents the registration year. I want to change this column to age. As the data is from 2010 I assume that the following statement should calculate the age but there is an error?

```
Select Model, Variant, EngineSize, RegYear, Mileage, Price, Sector from   sampledata
update sampledata
set RegYear = 2010 - RegYear
where sector = 'Van Derived Cars'
and mileage > 200
and regyear != -1
and price != 999999
```

Can someone please help. I feel this should be very easy to do but everything I try seems to fail!

Comment: What error/problem are you seeing?

Comment: there is a red line under 'update'

Comment: ignore what is underneath {where sector = 'Van Derived Cars'} that ensures SQL is not outputting irrelevant data

Comment: Do you get any specific errors when you run the query?

Comment: No, it just gives me error code 1064

Comment: So is this the step you would take to change the data in a column then? I am very new to SQL but from what I have read it seems that this should work

Comment: can u show us the schema of the sampledata table. And is this your executed query ?

Comment: Shouldn't you end the select statement with a `;`? Does it give a result?

Comment: ok so if I run this query: {Select Model, Variant, EngineSize, RegYear, Mileage, Price, Sector from   sampledata
where sector = 'Van Derived Cars'
and mileage > 200
and regyear != -1 and price != 999999} I get all my out out but with the registration year in 'RegYear

Comment: I am wanting the registration year to be replaced with age so I run this {Select Model, Variant, EngineSize, RegYear, Mileage, Price, Sector from   sampledata
update sampledata
set RegYear = 2010 - RegYear
where sector = 'Van Derived Cars'
and mileage > 200
and regyear != -1
and price != 999999} where I receive an error

Comment: Sorry the code is very unclear in the comment box....

Comment: I think the mechanism with which you are attempting to implement the age calculation is a horrible one and will not scale over time. You know when an event occurred. You know what today is. You can perform the calculation to determine the age. You replace your start date with the age and now you've lost the original date, but that's ok because you have age. The sun sets and now it's tomorrow. Is the Age still correct? Probably. 17 months from now, you've long forgotten about this one time conversion query - a business user is going to ask, is that age correct? How will you be able to prove it?

Comment: It's not a problem that the age will not change. I'm interested in the data from that point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error code 1064  :

This means you have an error in your SQL syntax.( `;` missed)

```
 Select Model, Variant, EngineSize, RegYear, Mileage, Price, Sector 
 from sampledata ;
 update sampledata
 set RegYear = 2010 - RegYear
 where sector = 'Van Derived Cars'
 and mileage > 200
 and regyear != -1
 and price != 999999;
```

> Mysql error  code 1175 :

If you are in a safe mode, you need to provide a key (ex. primary key) in the where clause or you can `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. That has gotten rid of the error but I still get the reg year outputted, not the age. A new error 1175 is displayed

Comment: show us the table schema please

Comment: When you say schema do you mean the table that is outputted? There is an awful lot of data....

Comment: @George Execute that first :  `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0; ` and then try again..

Comment: Ok thanks, I have just tried that. There is no error message but the reg year is still being outputted, not the age

Comment: good, now execute that : `SHOW COLUMNS FROM sampledata;` it will show us the schema of the table.

Comment: So is SHOW COLUMNS FROM sample data; just to output the table? I have the table outputted but it is showing the reg year not the age

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39185/discussion-between-yassine-laadidi-and-george).